# hazelcast-kubernetes Unable to start Embedded server

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, hazelcast

I'm trying to start a simple embedded hazelcast server in a spring boot application on kubernetes. 
I'm using hazelcast-kubernetes plugin and have followed the documentation [here](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes).
I tried both LoadBalancer and NodePort service types.

I also tried to deploy the sample application using [this example](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration/kubernetes/samples/embedded) (using the same docker image) and tried both LoadBalancer and NodePort service types.

In both cases I get the below error after 10 retries to connect to Kubernetes Master.
Where a.b.c.d is the IP address of the kubernetes master node.

```
2020-03-09 18:20:57.322  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.h.c.LifecycleService                   : [a.b.c.d]:5701 [dev] [3.12] [a.b.c.d]:5701 is STARTING
2020-03-09 18:20:57.820  WARN 1 --- [           main] c.h.k.RetryUtils                         : Couldn't connect to the Kubernetes master, [1] retrying in 1 seconds...
2020-03-09 18:20:59.339  WARN 1 --- [           main] c.h.k.RetryUtils                         : Couldn't connect to the Kubernetes master, [2] retrying in 2 seconds...
2020-03-09 18:21:01.713  WARN 1 --- [           main] c.h.k.RetryUtils                         : Couldn't connect to the Kubernetes master, [3] retrying in 3 seconds...
2020-03-09 18:21:05.113  WARN 1 --- [           main] c.h.k.RetryUtils                         : Couldn't connect to the Kubernetes master, [4] retrying in 5 seconds...
2020-03-09 18:21:10.198  WARN 1 --- [           main] c.h.k.RetryUtils                         : Couldn't connect to the Kubernetes master, [5] retrying in 7 seconds...
2020-03-09 18:21:17.807  WARN 1 --- [           main] c.h.k.RetryUtils                         : Couldn't connect to the Kubernetes master, [6] retrying in 11 seconds...
2020-03-09 18:21:49.216  WARN 1 --- [           main] c.h.k.RetryUtils                         : Couldn't connect to the Kubernetes master, [7] retrying in 17 seconds...
2020-03-09 18:22:06.319  WARN 1 --- [           main] c.h.k.RetryUtils                         : Couldn't connect to the Kubernetes master, [8] retrying in 25 seconds...
2020-03-09 18:22:31.963  WARN 1 --- [           main] c.h.k.RetryUtils                         : Couldn't connect to the Kubernetes master, [9] retrying in 38 seconds...
2020-03-09 18:23:15.423  WARN 1 --- [           main] c.h.k.RetryUtils                         : Couldn't connect to the Kubernetes master, [10] retrying in 57 seconds...
2020-03-09 18:24:23.099 ERROR 1 --- [           main] c.h.i.c.i.DiscoveryJoiner                : [a.b.c.d]:5701 [dev] [3.12] Failure in KubernetesClient
com.hazelcast.kubernetes.KubernetesClientException: Failure in KubernetesClient
        at com.hazelcast.kubernetes.DefaultKubernetesClient.callGet(DefaultKubernetesClient.java:109) ~[hazelcast-kubernetes-1.3.1.jar!/:?]
        at com.hazelcast.kubernetes.DefaultKubernetesClient.endpointsByName(DefaultKubernetesClient.java:88) ~[hazelcast-kubernetes-1.3.1.jar!/:?]
        .
        .
        .       
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [main.jar:?]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: kubernetes.default.svc
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
```

In the second case, where I'm using leszko's [sample](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration/kubernetes/samples/embedded), the ip address it tries to connect to is the IP of the POD.

> [190.168.1.194]:5701 [dev] [3.11] Failure in KubernetesClient

*190.168.1.194 is the POD's IP address*

I added the below env to the deployment yaml, but doesn't look like it is overriding this varaible.

```
env:
           - name: service-name
             value: "hazelcast-embedded"

Kubernetes Discovery properties: { service-dns: null, service-dns-timeout: 5, service-name: null, service-port: 0, service-label: null, service-label-value: true, namespace: default, resolve-not-ready-addresses: false, kubernetes-master: https://kubernetes.default.svc}
```

Comment: Are you able to try with com.hazelcast:hazelcast:4.0 and com.hazelcast:hazelcast-kubernetes:2.0.1 ? All you need to is enable the Kubernetes discovery and set the DNS to `service-dns: yourservicename.default.svc.cluster.local'

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just tries what you suggested. I get this error

`Mar 10, 2020 7:54:12 PM com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.integration.DiscoveryService
WARNING: [10.224.95.88]:5701 [dev] [4.0] DNS lookup for serviceDns 'haz-server.default.svc.cluster.local' failed
javax.naming.CommunicationException: DNS error [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out]; remaining name 'haz-server.default.svc.cluster.local'        at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.query(DnsClient.java:309)
        at com.sun.jndi.dns.Resolver.query(Resolver.java:81)`

Comment: Could it be like you are having DNS related issues in your kubernetes cluster?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21521309/java-jndi-dns-error-receive-timed-out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have an issue with your Kubernetes cluster itself.

1. First you try to use Hazelcast Kubernetes Discovery strategy [Kubernetes API](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes#kubernetes-api), which makes a REST call to Kubernetes master. Kubernetes master should be always accessible from your POD by the hostname `kubernetes.default.svc`. In your case, it's not found.
2. Then, you try to use Hazelcast Kubernetes Discovery strategy [DNS Lookup](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes#dns-lookup), which uses service DNS to resolve Hazelcast members. In your case, as mentioned by @Mesut, it's not resolving correctly the DNS of a service.

Comment: It must be an issue with my local K8s setup. I tried to run this on a GCP k8s cluster and I was able to start my application using both Kubernetes API and DNS discovery methods.

I just had 2 follow up questions. If you can comment here, it'd be great
1. Between Kubernetes API & DNS, is there a recommended way?
2. How does the client make connection to the hazelcast server? 
I know we just need @Autowired hazelcastInstance, but internally what is the client looking for to make connection.